# If I write a paper as PI, is it best to be first or last author?

Tags: publications, authorship, cv, physics, author-order

I'm a physicist at a national lab. I recently became head of a group at my lab and am currently writing a journal paper with a few of the people in my group.

Is it better to put myself as first author (indicating I was the lead researcher on the project) or last author (indicating I am the group leader/PI)?

Comment: This is field dependent, I think.

Comment: Well, were you the lead researcher or the group lead leading the project? Sounds like this should be one of your last first-author papers.

Comment: See also: [What does author order indicate?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/535/what-does-author-order-indicate) or [Author order when senior and lead author same person](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/87592/author-order-when-senior-and-lead-author-same-person)

Comment: To clarify, for my discipline (quantum/physics), first author indicates primary person who did the research and last author represents the PI. If I am both, is either "better" for e.g. CV and or future job prospects?

Comment: At a national lab you might want to keep publishing papers of each type. I'd suggest you ask about the local expectations. Apart from that, see also [When is it most appropriate to transition from first to senior author?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/82059/17254), [What author position on publications is best for early-career academics in physics: First or last author?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/85394/17254), [When do researchers decide to be listed as last author?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/104745/17254)

Answer (score 1):

Different fields attribute different meanings to authorship order.

In the future, you will be taken up more by your group responsibilities and will have less chance to spend time on research. Thus, first author positions will become rarer, which indicates that you should lean towards it if you have a choice. If you are still in the early stages, you might consider moving writing and researching tasks related to the paper to one of your colleagues and end up functioning as the PI and indicating this by the last position.